# Campagnolo and Shimano compatability

Tags: parts

so I have some 9 speed campy shifters and a 9 speed shimano wheelset lying around, I'd like to know if they can work with each other so I can save some money as I'm planning on building/ upgrading a bike in the near future with these parts. So in short, is Campagnolo and Shimano in any way compatible with each other?

Comment: Idea - Since you have the parts already, suggest you dry-fit them and see how it goes.  If you're short a critical part like a cassette or chain, this is of limited value.  I had to file my old-school hanger nut to get a 9 speed shimano wheel in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Campagnolo has two cable pull numbers for 9 speed, theres 3.0 and 3.2 mm per click.

Shimano 9 speed is 2.5mm of cable pull per click, so you're out of luck.

---

I'd suggest selling on the campy shifters on ebay and use the proceeds to fund some boring but common shimano ones.

Or go the other way and look for a campag rear wheel and derailleurs, but these will likely be more rare and therefore cost more.

Reference link: http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/

Answer (score 0):

I had a 9 speed Tiagra group on a 2000ish bike.  When the Shifter broke I replaced them with Veloce 9 speed ergos and rear mech.  The rear der movement of Campag 9 sped was close enough to 9 speed shimano that shifting was fine on the shimano cassette.